# Meteor iron-router action calling twice

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm need to get params from url using iron-router, my query string is:

```
http://localhost:3000/login/&status=ok&access_token=f1f2fd9&name=usernameHere
```

But when i'm going to thir url i'm getting a double call of router action function.

Code:

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
    progressSpinner : false
});
Router.route('/login/:someParams', {
    name: 'login',
    path: '/login/:someParams',
    action: function() {
        console.log('action here');
    }           
});
```

Output in console:

```
action here
action here
```

So code runs twice.

How to fix this (question about double execution of router action function, not about how to get query params)?

Comment: The theme of "I'm confused because IR hooks run multiple times" is really common. Does the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25099549/meteor-why-is-iron-routers-onbeforeaction-called-multiple-times) solve your problem?

Comment: Seems yes, thank you David. You can add answer for votes and i'll close question